# how to load escaped character html content in webview

Tags: android, wordpress, encoding, webview

I am using json api in my wordpress site to get the posts in json format. And I am also retrieving this json response and store in the string variable.
I use 
`webview.loadData(html_value, "text/html", "UTF-8");`
to load data into my webview.
But it is not working with escaped character in HTML content. It displays the content in unknown format.
My json respone is

```html
<p style=\"text-align: left;\"><strong>\u0c9f\u0c97\u0cb0\u0cc1, \u0cae\u0cc8\u0caf\u0cc6\u0cb2\u0ccd\u0cb2\u0cbe \u0caa\u0cca\u0c97\u0cb0\u0cc1<\/strong>, \u0cb6\u0cc0\u0cb0\u0ccd\u0cb7\u0cbf\u0c95\u0cc6 \u0c85\u0c82\u0ca4\u0cc6 \u0c9a\u0cbf\u0ca4\u0ccd\u0cb0 \u0c9f\u0c97\u0cb0\u0cc1 \u0cac\u0cbf\u0ca1\u0cc1\u0c97\u0ca1\u0cc6\u0c97\u0cc2 \u0cae\u0cc1\u0ca8\u0ccd\u0ca8 \u0cad\u0cb0\u0ccd\u0c9c\u0cb0\u0cbf\u0caf\u0cbe\u0c97\u0cbf \u0c95\u0c82\u0ca1\u0cc1 \u0cac\u0c82\u0ca6\u0cbf\u0ca6\u0cc6, \u0c8e\u0cb2\u0ccd\u0cb2\u0cbf \u0c85\u0c82\u0ca4\u0cbf\u0ca6\u0cc0\u0cb0\u0cbe? \u0c88 \u0c9f\u0cc0\u0cb8\u0cb0\u0ccd \u0cb5\u0cbf\u0ca1\u0cbf\u0caf\u0ccb \u0ca8\u0ccb\u0ca1\u0cbf.<\/p>\r\nhttps:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=scekni9K2Mg\r\n<p style=\"text-align: left;\">\u0c95\u0cb0\u0cc1\u0ca8\u0cbe\u0ca1 \u0c9a\u0c95\u0ccd\u0cb0\u0cb5\u0cb0\u0ccd\u0ca4\u0cbf \u0ca1\u0cbe \u0cb6\u0cbf\u0cb5\u0cb0\u0cbe\u0c9c\u0ccd \u0c95\u0cc1\u0cae\u0cbe\u0cb0\u0ccd \u0c85\u0cad\u0cbf\u0ca8\u0caf\u0ca6 \u0ca6\u0cc1\u0ca8\u0cbf\u0caf\u0cbe \u0cb8\u0cc2\u0cb0\u0cbf \u0ca8\u0cbf\u0cb0\u0ccd\u0ca6\u0cc7\u0cb6\u0ca8\u0ca6 \u0c9a\u0cbf\u0ca4\u0ccd\u0cb0 \u0c9f\u0c97\u0cb0\u0cc1 \u0cae\u0cca\u0ca8\u0ccd\u0ca8\u0cc6\u0caf\u0cb7\u0ccd\u0c9f\u0cc7 \u0c9a\u0cbf\u0ca4\u0ccd\u0cb0\u0ca6 \u0c9f\u0cc0\u0cb8\u0cb0\u0ccd \u0cac\u0cbf\u0ca1\u0cc1\u0c97\u0ca1\u0cc6 \u0cae\u0cbe\u0ca1\u0cbf\u0ca6\u0cc6. \u0cb5\u0cbf\u0cb6\u0cc7\u0cb7\u0cb5\u0cc6\u0c82\u0ca6\u0cb0\u0cc6 \u0c87\u0ca6\u0cc6 \u0cae\u0cca\u0ca6\u0cb2 \u0cac\u0cbe\u0cb0\u0cbf\u0c97\u0cc6 \u0c92\u0cac\u0ccd\u0cac \u0ca8\u0cbe\u0caf\u0c95\u0ca8 \u0c85\u0cad\u0cbf\u0cae\u0cbe\u0ca8\u0cbf \u0cac\u0cb3\u0c97 \u0caa\u0cc2\u0cb0\u0ccd\u0ca4\u0cbf \u0c95\u0cbe\u0cb0\u0ccd\u0caf\u0c95\u0ccd\u0cb0\u0cae \u0c85\u0caf\u0ccb\u0c9a\u0cbf\u0cb8\u0cbf\u0ca4\u0ccd\u0ca4\u0cc1. \u0cac\u0cbf\u0ca1\u0cc1\u0c97\u0ca1\u0cc6 \u0c86\u0c97\u0cbf 24\u0c97\u0c82\u0c9f\u0cc6 \u0cae\u0cca\u0ca6\u0cb2\u0cc7 \u0c92\u0c82\u0ca6\u0cc1 \u0cae\u0cc1\u0c95\u0ccd\u0c95\u0cbe\u0cb2\u0cc1 \u0cb2\u0c95\u0ccd\u0cb7\u0c95\u0ccd\u0c95\u0cbf\u0c82\u0ca4 \u0c9c\u0cbe\u0cb8\u0ccd\u0ca4\u0cbf \u0c9c\u0ca8 \u0c88 \u0cb5\u0cbf\u0ca1\u0cbf\u0caf\u0ccb \u0ca8\u0ccb\u0ca1\u0cbf \u0caa\u0ccd\u0cb0\u0cb6\u0c82\u0cb6\u0cbf\u0cb8\u0cbf\u0ca6\u0ccd\u0ca6\u0cbe\u0cb0\u0cc6. \u0c87\u0ca6\u0cb0\u0cb2\u0ccd\u0cb2\u0cbf \u0c97\u0cae\u0ca8 \u0cb8\u0cc6\u0cb3\u0cc6\u0caf\u0cb2\u0cc1 \u0cb9\u0cb2\u0cb5\u0cbe\u0cb0\u0cc1 \u0cb5\u0cbf\u0cb7\u0caf\u0c97\u0cb3\u0cbf\u0cb5\u0cc6. \u0cb8\u0cc1\u0c95\u0ccd\u0c95\u0cbe \u0cb8\u0cc2\u0cb0\u0cbf \u0ca8\u0cbf\u0cb0\u0ccd\u0ca6\u0cc7\u0cb6\u0ca8, \u0cb6\u0cbf\u0cb5\u0ca3\u0ccd\u0ca3 \u0cae\u0ca4\u0ccd\u0ca4\u0cc6 \u0cb2\u0cbe\u0c82\u0c97\u0ccd \u0cb9\u0cbf\u0ca1\u0cbf\u0ca6\u0ccd\u0ca6\u0cbf\u0ca6\u0ccd\u0ca6\u0cbe\u0cb0\u0cc6, \u0cae\u0cb9\u0cc7\u0c82\u0ca6\u0ccd\u0cb0 \u0cb8\u0cbf\u0c82\u0cb9 \u0c85\u0cb5\u0cb0 \u0c95\u0ccd\u0caf\u0cbe\u0cae\u0cc6\u0cb0\u0cbe \u0cb5\u0cb0\u0ccd\u0c95\u0ccd, \u0c85\u0cb7\u0ccd\u0c9f\u0cc7 \u0c96\u0ca6\u0cb0\u0ccd \u0c87\u0cb0\u0ccb \u0c9a\u0cb0\u0ca3\u0ccd \u0cb0\u0cbe\u0c9c\u0ccd \u0cb0\u0cb5\u0cb0 \u0cb9\u0cbf\u0ca8\u0ccd\u0ca8\u0cb2\u0cc6 \u0cb8\u0c82\u0c97\u0cc0\u0ca4.<\/p>\r\n<p style=\"text-align: center;\"><iframe src=\"https:\/\/w.soundcloud.com\/player\/?url=https%3A\/\/api.soundcloud.com\/tracks\/352880786&amp;color=%23ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;show_teaser=true&amp;visual=true\" width=\"100%\" height=\"300\" frameborder=\"no\" scrolling=\"no\"><\/iframe><\/p>\r\n\u0cae\u0cca\u0ca6\u0cb2 \u0cac\u0cbe\u0cb0\u0cbf\u0c97\u0cc6 \u0ca7\u0ca8\u0c82\u0c9c\u0caf\u0ccd \u0cb5\u0cb8\u0cbf\u0cb7\u0ccd\u0ca0 \u0c92\u0cb3\u0c97\u0cc2\u0ca1\u0cbf \u0c96\u0cb3 \u0ca8\u0c9f \u0c86\u0c97\u0cbf\u0ca6\u0ccd\u0ca6\u0cbe\u0cb0\u0cc6. \u0c9f\u0cc0\u0cb8\u0cb0\u0ccd \u0cb5\u0cbf\u0ca1\u0cbf\u0caf\u0ccb \u0ca8 \u0cb9\u0cbf\u0ca8\u0ccd\u0ca8\u0cb2\u0cc6 \u0cb8\u0c82\u0c97\u0cc0\u0ca4 \u0c95\u0cc2\u0ca1 \u0ca4\u0c82\u0ca1 \u0cac\u0cbf\u0ca1\u0cc1\u0c97\u0ca1\u0cc6 \u0c97\u0cca\u0cb3\u0cbf\u0cb8\u0cbf\u0ca6\u0cc6. \u0c9a\u0cbf\u0ca4\u0ccd\u0cb0 \u0cb6\u0ca4\u0ca6\u0cbf\u0ca8 \u0caa\u0cc2\u0cb0\u0cc8\u0cb8\u0cb2\u0cbf \u0c85\u0ca8\u0ccd\u0ca8\u0ccb\u0ca6\u0cc1 \u0c8e\u0cb2\u0ccd\u0cb2\u0cb0 \u0c86\u0cb6\u0caf.","excerpt":"\u0c9f\u0c97\u0cb0\u0cc1, \u0cae\u0cc8\u0caf\u0cc6\u0cb2\u0ccd\u0cb2\u0cbe \u0caa\u0cca\u0c97\u0cb0\u0cc1, \u0cb6\u0cc0\u0cb0\u0ccd\u0cb7\u0cbf\u0c95\u0cc6 \u0c85\u0c82\u0ca4\u0cc6 \u0c9a\u0cbf\u0ca4\u0ccd\u0cb0 \u0c9f\u0c97\u0cb0\u0cc1 \u0cac\u0cbf\u0ca1\u0cc1\u0c97\u0ca1\u0cc6\u0c97\u0cc2 \u0cae\u0cc1\u0ca8\u0ccd\u0ca8 \u0cad\u0cb0\u0ccd\u0c9c\u0cb0\u0cbf\u0caf\u0cbe\u0c97\u0cbf \u0c95\u0c82\u0ca1\u0cc1 \u0cac\u0c82\u0ca6\u0cbf\u0ca6\u0cc6, \u0c8e\u0cb2\u0ccd\u0cb2\u0cbf \u0c85\u0c82\u0ca4\u0cbf\u0ca6\u0cc0\u0cb0\u0cbe? \u0c88 \u0c9f\u0cc0\u0cb8\u0cb0\u0ccd \u0cb5\u0cbf\u0ca1\u0cbf\u0caf\u0ccb \u0ca8\u0ccb\u0ca1\u0cbf. \u0c95\u0cb0\u0cc1\u0ca8\u0cbe\u0ca1 \u0c9a\u0c95\u0ccd\u0cb0\u0cb5\u0cb0\u0ccd\u0ca4\u0cbf \u0ca1\u0cbe \u0cb6\u0cbf\u0cb5\u0cb0\u0cbe\u0c9c\u0ccd \u0c95\u0cc1\u0cae\u0cbe\u0cb0\u0ccd \u0c85\u0cad\u0cbf\u0ca8\u0caf\u0ca6 \u0ca6\u0cc1\u0ca8\u0cbf\u0caf\u0cbe \u0cb8\u0cc2\u0cb0\u0cbf \u0ca8\u0cbf\u0cb0\u0ccd\u0ca6\u0cc7\u0cb6\u0ca8\u0ca6 \u0c9a\u0cbf\u0ca4\u0ccd\u0cb0 \u0c9f\u0c97\u0cb0\u0cc1 \u0cae\u0cca\u0ca8\u0ccd\u0ca8\u0cc6\u0caf\u0cb7\u0ccd\u0c9f\u0cc7 \u0c9a\u0cbf\u0ca4\u0ccd\u0cb0\u0ca6 \u0c9f\u0cc0\u0cb8\u0cb0\u0ccd \u0cac\u0cbf\u0ca1\u0cc1\u0c97\u0ca1\u0cc6 \u0cae\u0cbe\u0ca1\u0cbf\u0ca6\u0cc6. \u0cb5\u0cbf\u0cb6\u0cc7\u0cb7\u0cb5\u0cc6\u0c82\u0ca6\u0cb0\u0cc6 \u0c87\u0ca6\u0cc6 \u0cae\u0cca\u0ca6\u0cb2 \u0cac\u0cbe\u0cb0\u0cbf\u0c97\u0cc6 \u0c92\u0cac\u0ccd\u0cac \u0ca8\u0cbe\u0caf\u0c95\u0ca8 \u0c85\u0cad\u0cbf\u0cae\u0cbe\u0ca8\u0cbf \u0cac\u0cb3\u0c97 \u0caa\u0cc2\u0cb0\u0ccd\u0ca4\u0cbf \u0c95\u0cbe\u0cb0\u0ccd\u0caf\u0c95\u0ccd\u0cb0\u0cae \u0c85\u0caf\u0ccb\u0c9a\u0cbf\u0cb8\u0cbf\u0ca4\u0ccd\u0ca4\u0cc1. \u0cac\u0cbf\u0ca1\u0cc1\u0c97\u0ca1\u0cc6 \u0c86\u0c97\u0cbf 24\u0c97\u0c82\u0c9f\u0cc6 \u0cae\u0cca\u0ca6\u0cb2\u0cc7 \u0c92\u0c82\u0ca6\u0cc1 \u0cae\u0cc1\u0c95\u0ccd\u0c95\u0cbe\u0cb2\u0cc1 \u0cb2\u0c95\u0ccd\u0cb7\u0c95\u0ccd\u0c95\u0cbf\u0c82\u0ca4 \u0c9c\u0cbe\u0cb8\u0ccd\u0ca4\u0cbf \u0c9c\u0ca8 \u0c88 &hellip;
```

I have also used `String webdata= StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(jsonHTMLContent);` to convert escaped character into UTF-8 But no use. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**how to load escaped character html content in webview.**

**Note : please remove extra add slashes.**

```
 web.loadData("<p style='text-align: left;'><strong>Testing</strong></p><p style='text-align: center;'><iframe src='https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/352880786&amp;color=%23ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;show_teaser=true&amp;visual=true' width='100%' height='300' frameborder='no' scrolling='no'></iframe></p>\n","text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I want to load the data dynamically. Not the static HTML content. and also the data contains some Kannada character.

Comment: ok. please update your web service. and use stripslashes(); function in php webservice

Comment: What is the encoding format of ' \u0cae\u0cc8\u0caf\u0cc6\u0cb2\u0ccd\u0cb2\u0cbe '